# What is the area of BEC shaded triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

Area of $ABC$ triangle is $24\,\mathrm{cm}^2,$ $\frac{BM}{AB}=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{AN}{AC}=\frac{1}{3}$. E is a midpoint of MN. What is the area of $BEC$ shaded triangle?

I don't know how to calculate the area of the shaded triangle, All I can think of is using triangle similarity or some sort of ratios with area/sides but I can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop perpendiculars from $M$, $E$ and $N$ to $BC$ lets call their intersections by $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ respectively. $MNZX$ is a trapezoid and $EY$ is its' midline so:
$$EY=\frac{MX+NZ}{2}$$
So if by $[F]$ we denote the area of a shape $F$ we get:
$$[BEC]=\frac{[BMC]+[BNC]}{2}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}[ABC]+\frac{2}{3}[ABC]}{2}=\frac{1}{2}[ABC]=12$$
Where in the middle we made use of the fact that for the triangles that share the altitude the ratio of their areas is the same as ratio of their sides.

Comment: I don't understand this, what happened to $EY$? did we even use it, I also don't understand BEC equation, why is it half of that 2 triangles

Comment: @bartlyajames $EY$ is the midline in trapezoid $MNZX$ and therefore it's the arithmetic mean of its bases. Now we multiply the first equation in my answer by $\frac{1}{2}BC$ to convert this equality of lengths into an equality of areas, since $BC$ is the base of $BEC$, $BMC$ and $BNC$ and $EY$, $MX$, $NZ$ are their respetive heights.

Comment: Oh I get it now, BEC Area equation works cause it's same for their heights. I'd never notice these triangles to get to the area of BEC though, what was your thought process? just experience? some tips would be great

Comment: @bartlyajames It's just the knowledge and awareness of two lemmas: first that if the triangles share their height the ratio of their areas is the same as the ratio of their bases and the second is this fact about averaging them. The second one can be generalized: if the point $E$ divides the segment $MN$ in the arbitrary $p:q$ ratio, then we would have $[BEC](p+q)=q[BMC]+p[BNC]$ - using these two tricks will help you solve every problem of this type.

Answer (score 0):

If $[\triangle BEM]=a$, then $[\triangle AEN]=[\triangle AEM]=2a$.

$[\triangle CEN]=4a$ and $[\triangle ABC]=4a\times\dfrac32\times3=18a$.

$18a=24$ $\implies $ $a=\dfrac43$.

$[\triangle BEC]=18a-9a=12$.